# $divide is mongoose is giving "Cast to Number failed for value"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here i am trying to update the 'rating' field of my document by taking average of previously existing value of the rating field and newly sent rating value.

this is my rating field specification in the model

```json
rating: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      required: true,
},
```

this is my request body and controller function

```js
const { newRating, bookID, userName, comment } = req.body;

const updateRating = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: bookID },
    {
      rating: { $divide: [{ $inc: { rating: Number(newRating) } }, 2] },
      $inc: { numOfRatings: 1 },
    },
    { new: true }
    );
```

and i am using postman to send client side data

here for example the rating field has previously set value of 4.1 and i am sending 5 as new rating in req.body then i want the rating field to have an updated value of 4.55 ((4.1+5)/2)

and this is the output i am getting in postman

{
"message": "Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$divide': [ { '$inc': [Object] }, 2 ] }" (type Object) at path "rating"",
"stack": "CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$divide': [ { '$inc': [Object] }, 2 ] }" (type Object) at path "rating"\n    at model.Query.exec (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4891:21)\n    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4990:15)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"
}

i tried few things seeing mongodb solutions but it is not working out for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work:

```js
const updateRating = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { _id: bookID },
  [{
    "$set": {
      "rating": { "$divide": [{ "$sum": ["$rating", 5] }, 2] },
      "numOfRatings": { "$sum": ["$numOfRatings", 1 ] }
    }
  }],
  { new: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$divide` is only available for Aggregation framework, so you need to change your `update` (second) input like this:

```
await Book.findByIdAndUpdate({
  _id: bookID
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "rating": { "$divide": [{ "$sum": ["$rating", Number(newRating)] }, 2] },
      "numOfRatings": { "$sum": ["$numOfRatings", 1 ] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4DgTgsyG0EP)

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir but your solution works in mongoDB and i want it in mongoose. i tried to rewrite your logic in mongoose but i got error: "message": "Cast to Number failed for value \"{ '$avg': [ '$rating', 5 ] }\" (type Object) at path \"rating\"",
    `const updateRating = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: bookID },
    {
      $set: {
        rating: { $divide: [{ $inc: { rating: rating } }, 2] },
      },
      $inc: { numOfRatings: 1 },
    },
    { new: true }
    );`

Comment: You didn't map it correctly. I updated the answer for Mongoose. Can you try it again?